# ZPL language file (Zebra) use for print into Godex printer

Tags: printing, label, compatibility, zebra-printers, zpl

Goodmorning,
I have a ZPL file (text file inside) used for a Zebra printer, and I need to print that with a new Godex printer. 
I have already installed the driver of the Godex printer and set the dimensions of the labels.

Is there any method to use the "ZPL code" to print into the Godex printer? I've read on Internet that they are compatible, but I can't find how I can use them togheter. Is any other driver necessary?

Thanks for help

Comment: This question has little to do with coding.

Comment: @person i have a .txt file which contains ZPL code like: ^XA                                                          
^FO50,50^A0,60,60^FDTest^FS       
^XZ  But i am unable to print it's output on Zebra ZTC gc420t (EPL) printer. What should i do?

Comment: @prgrm i have a .txt file which contains ZPL code like: ^XA                                                          
^FO50,50^A0,60,60^FDTest^FS       
^XZ  But i am unable to print it's output on Zebra ZTC gc420t (EPL) printer. What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Old topic but I have the answer: Yes, it is possible.

Install Godex printer as Generic Text Only printer in windows.

IMPORTANT: you have to "reset" the printer if you change paper size. Turn on the printer with its 2 buttons pressed (DT4x model) until you hear 3 beeps. Wait a bit. Then the printer "takes size" of the paper. You must do this when you change paper size or it won't print fine.

After that, open your ZPL file with a text editor and print it to that generic printer and that's all.

Regards.